# I get an error 'unexcepted null value' (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to make a simple calculator. I wanted to do it all in one function instead of defining functions separately for each operation, but I'm getting an error and I couldn't figure out why I was getting this error.

```
  late num numberOne, numberTwo;
  String result = '';

  mathFunction(String text) {
    if (textControllerTwo != '0') {
      numberOne = num.tryParse(textControllerOne.text)!;
      numberTwo = num.tryParse(textControllerTwo.text)!;

      switch (text) {
        case 'collection':
          return result = (numberOne + numberTwo).toString();
        case 'interest':
          return result = (numberOne - numberTwo).toString();
        case 'multiply':
          return result = (numberOne * numberTwo).toString();
        case 'divided':
          return result = (numberOne / numberTwo).toString();
      }
    } else {
      return result = 'Number cannot be divided by 0';
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: You need to add `default:` to your switch.

Comment: A warning pops up;
"The label 'defult' isn't used.
Try removing the label, or using it in either a 'break' or 'continue' statement."

Comment: use `default`. And `num.tryParse` can return `null`. See https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/num/tryParse.html

Comment: I didn't know that tryparse returns null. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `default` clause to your `switch` statement.
2. Give a default value for each `num` value from tryParse.
3. Remove `setState(() {});` because you must not give a `side effect` when calling your function/method.
4. No need to use a class/file scope variable (`numberOne`, `numberTwo`, `result`) for your function scope code.
5. Give a return type for your function/method.

here your simplified code:

```
  // return a string result from mathFunction.
  String mathFunction(String text) {
    if (textControllerTwo != '0') {
      
      // Give 0 if parse failed.
      num numberOne = num.tryParse(textControllerOne.text)??0;
      num numberTwo = num.tryParse(textControllerTwo.text)??0;

      switch (text) {
        case 'collection':
          return (numberOne + numberTwo).toString();
        case 'interest':
          return (numberOne - numberTwo).toString();
        case 'multiply':
          return (numberOne * numberTwo).toString();
        case 'divided':
          return (numberOne / numberTwo).toString();
        default:
          return "ERR"; 
      }
    } else {
      return 'Number cannot be divided by 0';
    }
  }
```

Comment: This fixed the error but button press is not working. How can I solve this? 
<code>ElevatedButton( 
   onPressed: mathFunction('plus'), 
   child: const Text('Plus'),)
</code>

<code>
buttonFunction(String text) { setState(() => mathFunction(text)); }
</code>

Comment: `onPressed` property needs `void Function` but the `mathFunction` is `String Function`, hence the problem. You can use `onPressed: () => mathFunction('plus'). But it still won't handle the result returned by the `mathFunction`. Please see https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#a-basic-dart-program

Answer (score 0):

It is better to get numberOne, numberTwo in methods arguments and make them not optional or use the required annotaiton.
make sure textControllerOne.text and textControllerTwo.text and text is not null.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work